# Last Day of Month in Optic Query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

Is there any function available in Optic API to identify last day of a month?

I have requirement to identify a date whether its last day of a month or not.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding one day to the date/dateTime, and then seeing if the month has changed using `sql.month()`, ie:

```
op.fromView('main', 'expenses')
  .bindAs('nextDay', op.sql.timestampadd('SQL_TSI_DAY', 1, op.col("submitted")))
  .where(op.ne(op.sql.month(op.col("submitted")),op.sql.month(op.col("nextDay")))
  .result();
```

Comment: I couldn't find corresponding function( op.sql.timestampadd) for xquery, Also getting undefined error for op:bind-as function

Comment: @ramz123, are you using latest MarkLogic?

Comment: @grtjn i am using Mark Logic 10.0-4.2

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to add a day to a timestamp. You can add a 1 day interval to it instead. op.bindAs() is recent, but you can do the same with select expressions instead.